# Clicking on Enter button without making any changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, label

I'm creating a form with multiple labels, and I used this javascript so I can click on the **Enter** button (in the keyboard) without jumping into the **submit** button (in the form), the following is working well but just in 1 label, how can I using it for all the labels without **copy & past it** changing the label id?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#text1').keydown(function(event){
            if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById("text1").value = document.getElementById("text1").value + "\n";
                return false;
            }
        });

        $('#text2').keydown(function(event){
            if(event.keyCode == 13) {
                event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById("text2").value = document.getElementById("text2").value + "\n";
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

    ...
    ...

</script>
```

Comment: Use classes or `$('FORM_ID :input')`...Which will select all the input elements....

Comment: what if their IDs are different, as I used them in some other scripts which are different

Comment: You don't need ids...`$(':input').keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});`

Comment: Thank you @RayonDabre, this has been resolved

Answer (score 0):

Since you are binding your key listener to `$('#text1')` and `$('#text2')`, it will only listen when your key is pressed while focusing these elements.

You have to bind your listener to a different selector that catches all your inputs, eg.:

```
$('.form-class input').keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
         ...
    }
});
```